# How does kotlin " when" decide what member of a generic sealed class it must return?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I only have a vague idea of the way `when` works regarding generic sealed classes, so please explain it for me.
I have this sealed class.

```
sealed class UiState<out T: Any>{
        data class Error<T: Any>(val errorMessage: String): UiState<T>()
        data class Success<T: Any>(val data: T): UiState<T>()
}
```

This class is added later to make it easier to understand the function:

```
sealed class Result<out T: Any>{
    data class Success<T: Any>(val data: T): Result<T>()
    class Error(val exception: UseCaseException): Result<Nothing>()
}
```

And a function to show an error or some data on the UI and `result.data` is a list of names to be shown: `List<Name>`

```
 

 fun convert(result: Result):UiState<result.data> = when(result)
      {
        is Result.Success -> UiState.Success(result.data)
        is Result.Error   -> UiState.Error("An error has occurred.")
 }
```

Why does `convert` always return `UiState<result.data>`? Why doesn't `convert` think that it must return a `UiState.Error` - a `String`, too when an error occurs?
P.S
Here is what I reason about it. When I read the `UiState` code, I noticed that the `Error` class does not use any `T` type, so the type of the whole `UiState` is decided by the `Success` class. That is why `when` always returns `UiState<result.data>`.

Comment: What is `Result`? And what is `:UiState<result.data>`? That is not valid syntax.

Comment: Did you mean to write `fun <T: Any> convert(result: Result<T>): UiState<T>` or something like that perhaps?

Comment: @Sweeper No. It is not a generic function. I have edited the code. Could you have another look.

Comment: **The code you showed still does not compile.** Did you mean `fun convert(result: Result<List<Name>>):UiState<List<Name>>`?

Comment: Yes, it goes like that. In the code you actually convert the `result.data`  to UiState.data. Hence the name `convert`.

Answer (score 0):

I’m reading between the lines since your syntax of the `convert` function is invalid in multiple ways.

The T of your Error instance does not somehow become a String just because the Error class happens to have a String property in it. Your Error class doesn’t even use its `T` generic for anything so it doesn’t need to define one. But regardless, if the function reaches the branch where it creates an Error instance, it is treating it as an inferred T type, so it simply makes it match. This works because your Error constructor doesn’t use T.

Your error class could be defined without specifying a generic type (since it doesn’t use one anyway) like this:

```
data class Error(val errorMessage: String): UiState<Nothing>()
```

Since Nothing is conceptually the subtype of everything, this makes it so Error can be upcast to a UiState of any type T.

Comment: Thank you. This is not code written by me and I think you have pointed out what I wanted to know: `UiState.Error` does not need any `T` as does `Result.Error`. I have even changed the code to : data class Success<T: Any>(val data: T): `UiState<Nothing>()` and the function still does not report any error.